# k8s service connection refused

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have two k8s clusters running in Azure. I want to reach an IP from Cluster A which is exposed in Cluster B. The IP(10.148.157.253) is exposed in Cluster B via load balancer.
In Cluster A I have created and endpoint and a service. When I curl from one of my pods http://10.148.157.253:8080 I get the result. However when I curl the service http://my-service.app.svc.cluster.local I get connection refused. Here are the configs from Cluster A:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: app
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: app
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: 10.148.157.253
   ports:
     - port: 8080
       protocol: TCP
```

This is how the load balancer in cluster B looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-loadbalancer
  namespace: app
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: "my-subnet"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.148.157.253
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

Do you know what might cause the issue that I can curl the load balancer IP, but not the service itself?

Comment: can you please add the output for `kubectl get svc -n app my-loadbalancer `?

Comment: If you have the possibility of attaching a DNS name to the IP address exposed from the LoadBalancer in Cluster B, I would go with an ExternamName service ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname )

Comment: @Emon46 this is the output

TYPE                 CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                  AGE
LoadBalancer   10.0.137.192      10.148.157.253    8080:30648/TCP   18h

Comment: @AndD I also thought about it as plan B. But the k8s documentation claims that my current approach should also work and it is also a bit easier. But if that doesn't work  I might try the external name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What really solved the problem is another service of type ExternalName which used the ip of the load balancer as an externalName.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: app
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: 10.148.157.253
```